# jquery.load() is not working on phonegap 3.0.0

Tags: jquery, cordova

I'm newbie developing a phonegap app. I already checked those posts: [jquery.load() not working on phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792954/jquery-load-not-working-on-phonegap) and [how to load pages using jquery load() in phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472131/how-to-load-pages-using-jquery-load-in-phonegap) and [jquery .load() function does not work under phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539079/jquery-load-function-does-not-work-under-phonegap)... but nothing seems to help.

I'm developing an app in phonegap with jquery and an external device to run it instead of an emulator. I have 2 html: **breakfast.html** and **tab.html**

My folder structure is:

```
▸ merges/               
▸ platforms/            
▸ plugins/              
▾ www/                  
  ▸ css/                
  ▸ img/                
  ▸ js/                 
  ▸ res/                
  ▸ spec/               
  ▾ static_pages/       
    ▾ layouts/          
        tab.html        
      breakfast.html    
    config.xml          
    icon.png            
    index.html          
    spec.html
```

My **Breakfast.html** is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                 
<html>                                                                                          
    <head>                                                                                      
        <meta charset="utf-8" />                                                                
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />                                 
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />          
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" />               
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/custom_forms.css" />                
        <title>Hello World</title>                                                              
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../phonegap.js"></script>                           
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/index.js"></script>                           
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>                   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>               
        <script type="text/javascript">                                                         
          app.initialize();                                                                     
        </script>                                                                                            
    </head>                                                                                     
     <body>                                                                                      
       <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
         XXXXXXX                                                                       
       </header>                                                                                 
         <div id="testing"></div>                                                                
         <script>$( "#testing" ).load( "layouts/tab.html #test" );</script>       
       <footer class="navbar" id="footer_bottom">                                                
         XXXXXXXX                                                              
       </footer>                                                                                 
     </body>    
</html>
```

My **tab.html** is:

```
<div id="test" style="width:100%;heigt:90px;background:black;color:white;">
  TESTING JQUERY                                                           
</div>
```

Regarding to official api.jquery.com/load page what I have to do to insert a part of an html file with an id I have to do next:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>load demo</title>
  <style>
  body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Footer navigation:</b>
<ol id="result"></ol>

<script>
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Does anyone faced this issue before and figure it out why?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Sorry, I'm developing for Android, and the device is a LG optimus 2X with android 4.2.2

Comment: I don't know what platform / device you're using and how your project is configured, but this problem may have something to do with the fact that phonegap applications use `file://` protocol and which is subject to strict security policies (shouldn't be as strict in WebView, but I'm not sure).

Comment: Sorry, I'm developing for Android, and the device is a LG optimus 2X with android 4.2.2... I'm gonna update the question.

Comment: If you were able to solve it, please add an answer to your own question. Or if you don't want to do that, then please delete your question.

Comment: I was writing it while you were deleting the solved tag ;) But you are wright I was slow.

Comment: Don't add "[SOLVED]" to the title, that's not how things work here. Posting self answer is correct, when you can mark it as accepted. (think it's 48 hours)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm newbie :oP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pawel (and the official http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide) I could figure out the solution. As he brilliantly suggest, the problem was with the whitelist domain configuration of my phonegap application. To solve it you have to edit your **your_app/www/config.xml** file and try to locate:

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
```

You must change it to:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

That's it. Now it works.

Thanks Pawel to show me the way ;)